# MongoConnectionException in local, not in remote

Tags: php, mongodb, azure

I am trying to connect to MongoDB from local (a Azure VM). I can connect when I try in my localhost workspace with the URL of the VM. But, when I try to connect in localhost there is a error:

At localhost:
`$m = new Mongo("mongodb://xxx.cloudapp.net:27017");`

At local VM:
`$m = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

I also try with: 127.0.0.1 and xxx.cloudapp.net.

This is the error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Permission denied' in /var/www/html/test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/test.php(8): Mongo->__construct('mongodb://local...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/test.php on line 8`

Comment: Did you try `$m = new MongoClient();` instead of those you listed? Also, are you sure you have permissions?

Comment: Yes, I try. Also I have the permission, otherwise I could not connect remotely.

Comment: @MatíasSanchez are you providing the same credentials locally as you do for remote? You don't show any (even mock) credentials above.

Comment: @NeilLunn do you mean auth (user/pass?)? I am using mongo without auth, just for test.

Comment: Fine. it's just that you said "Also I have the permission" above. I don't think I was wrong to interpret that as meaning "auth credentials". Is mongod possibly bound to an ip that is not 0.0.0.0 then? ps aux | grep mongod might show a bind option

Answer (score 1):

This is not a new issue. This is a regular issue, the problem is with the instalation.

Please check it out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.fedora

You have to run
`$ /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` and then restart apache service to fix the problem.

Thank you all